# How to view exact SQL syntax entered after entering

Tags: mysql, sql, syntax, workbench

I have created several tables and inserted data into the tables but I am now looking for a way to view the syntax that I entered to create each of the tables etc. Is this possible? I am using MySQL Workbench and have closed and re-opened the program several times throughout.

Comment: mysql features a "show create table" command. Consult the documentation for that. http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/show-create-table.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SQL:

```
show create table YourTable;
```